# django form submissionr return non "post" page

Tags: python, django

I have a select box and an input box that submits to a view in django.
When I submit it adds the value in django then the page reloads and the select box values are updated.
However if I press 'refresh' on that page, it tries to resubmit values again. How can I prevent this behavior, I would like the refresh after the POST to be a normal refresh of the page as if no POST had been submitted previously.

```
localhost/project/myview/3/3
```

I am trying to do a `"return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("myview"), firstid=3, secondid=3)"`
But it does not seem to be working, is this the right way of doing it and how do I fix this?

Comment: That behavior is handled by the browser. There is little you can do about it.

Comment: Redirecting is the right way to go and should prevent this from happening. What does your view look like?

Comment: No, this is a standard technique for form submissions: the view returns a 302 redirect to a URL that will not resubmit the form if reloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpResponseRedirect` only takes one parameter. You need to pass the id parameters to `reverse`:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("myview", kwargs={"firstid": 3, 
    "secondid": 3}))
```